# Airflow- configure smtp with office365 without credentials

Tags: email, smtp, office365, airflow

When a task/DAG fails I want to send an email to someone, and this does not work. We are using Office365 for this within the organisation and there should not be a need to authenticate with credentials user or password, as it is not done in other running projects. We are using the latest Airflow version released: 2.1.4

I have tried with the configuration in airflow config:

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp
email_conn_id = smtp_default
default_email_on_retry = True
default_email_on_failure = True

[smtp]
smtp_host = <the smtp host(Office365)>
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_mail_from = <the from email>
smtp_timeout = 30
smtp_retry_limit = 5
```

As I try this I get the following error in the airflow log when a task fails:

```
WARNING - section/key [smtp/smtp_user] not found in config
...
ERROR - Failed to send email to: ['<my email>']
```

Therefore I suppose I need to have a user if I use these options in the config.

There is also this information in the log:

```
PendingDeprecationWarning: Fetching SMTP credentials from configuration variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please set credentials using a connection instead.
```

I have been looking at this airflow documentation:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html

But it does not help me to understand how I should set up a connection to our smtp-server that is with Office365. The problem is as well that I don't have a user or password. I could possibly get them, but as it works without them in other running projects I am looking to do something similar.

Does anybody have some guidance in this matter?

Thank you

Comment: You can try to put some "fake"  user/password in the configuration and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @JarekPotiuk, however it did not work. The warning disappeared but the same error remains.

I am trying to look for any logs, and there appear to be none in airflow about the issue. I will look further for logs in office365.

Comment: I have now concluded that it is possible to send emails with a proper user/password so I know the connection between airflow and the server works, however using fake credentials or empty ones, or not setting them does not work for me. If anyone knows more or have examples of this working in their setup I'd be happy to hear suggestions.

Comment: @Shark32 you could create your own email backend and plug it into Airflow via settings `email_backend = path.to.your.module`. You could begin by copying the original from Airflow, found in `airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp` and  removing the code that does perform the user auth against the server.

Answer (score 1):

I have two project setup SMTP with authorizaiton, just setup as manual then work. I have a new client and their mail relay does not have user/password authentication. Their system configuration is set to an empty string, as shown below:

It will left **PendingDeprecationWarning** in log.

```
[smtp]
...
smtp_starttls = False
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user =
smtp_password =
```